# J2ME Polish Application icon defaulting

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, nokia, j2mepolish

I have a problem in a J2ME Polish app where basically we have 2 icons showing for the app (the menu icon and the in-app icon that shows up top).

If I compile with a single icon and set it in the build.xml file it loads it to both sides, although since the menu icon needs to be bigger than the in-app icon, the last one looks extremelly zoomed in.

When I do as stated in the docs and set the resources path in the build.xml with subdirectories on, if I only set a 24x24 icon, the in-app icon gets the new image but the menu icon doesn't. If I then set an icon and a 24x24 icon, it uses the other one as default for both areas.

Does anyone know how I can handle this?

PS: the test rig for this build is a Nokia N70, so if anyone knows the dimensions for the menu icon, I'd really appreciate the tip.

in the Nokia wiki, it states 24x24, but that's only for the in-app icon, not the menu one.

Comment: Have you tested this in emulator with different dimensions ?

Comment: sorry for late response, this was being tested on actual devices, emulator was working ok.

Answer (score 1):

Goncalo, you can visit the following site. It may help u.

[Link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/73508-J2ME-MIDlet-Icon)

Answer (score 1):

The screen size of the N70 is 176x208.